# How to add a chart title for gvisTimeline chart in R?

Tags: r, charts, timeline, googlevis

I am using [GoogleVis to plot timeline charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#Configuration_Options). Here is a sample code example  from [Jason Bryer's timeline package](http://jason.bryer.org/), showing the US presidents and UK prime ministers during World War II. :

```
require(timeline)
require(googleVis) 
data(ww2)
ww2$Person <- gsub("\\n" ," ", ww2$Person)
plot(gvisTimeline(ww2, barlabel="Person", rowlabel="Group",
                       start="StartDate", end="EndDate",
     options=list(width=590), chartid="ww2")
)
```

**My question:** How to add a title to the Timeline chart?
I tried the following but it did not work:

```
plot(gvisTimeline(ww2, barlabel="Person", rowlabel="Group",
                           start="StartDate", end="EndDate",
         options=list(width=590), title="Timeline Chart", chartid="ww2")
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a note: As I was annoyed by the required online connection of gvistimeline, I re-build the functionality using Plotly:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("shosaco/vistime")
vistime(ww2, events="Person", groups="Group", start="StartDate", end="EndDate", title="World War II")
```

[image]